# Tooltip z-Index in Multiple highcharts charts

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, z-index

I have many charts close to each other, but the tooltip got cut when it's on the other chart's div.

Here's the example [Tooltip got cut](http://jsfiddle.net/rpczP/)

I have use CSS to show the Tooltip complete but is not working

```
.highcharts-tooltip span {
    background-color:yellow;
    border:0px;
    z-index:9999 !important;
    overflow: visible;
}

.highcharts-container
{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Any help? please

Comment: Okay, I know each use case is different but what exactly are you trying to show the user here? These charts are much too small for usefulness. That aside, if you really need to have them this small and this close together, you can try to move the mouseover info tooltip to an external div rather than a tooltip box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.events.mouseOver). Instead of a tooltip you show the values you want to display in a different location.

Comment: Hi @wergeld I'm implementing Sparkling charts inside a table cell (bullets, trends, etc) along with other data. I just figure it out, I need to change the container's z-index dynamically since seems to be zero for default for all of them. Thanks

Comment: Ah, yes. Sparkline - usually there are just one chart per sparkline element so, yes, you have to handle the z-index of the tooltip.